# Responsive CSS image with fixed and centered background attachment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image inside it's parent div and have it fixed. I want to give it the collapsing header look (even though it's not really a header) so I'm using `background-attachment: fixed;` to keep it in place.

The problem with this approach is that when I then go to center the image with `background-position: center center;` the image is not being centered.

Obviously if I remove the `background-attachment: fixed;` line of CSS the image is then centered.

Is there any way to `background-attachment: fixed;` an image and center it?

```
.aparent {
    min-height:200px;
}
#achild {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442589031151-61d5645469d7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=86aed4d82f9ab1324e46ae97b4cd98e1);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Pen showing the code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoBJpR
(remove the `background-attachment:fixed;` to show how it should look)

Thanks.

Edit: pen broke

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: He did include the desired behavior: (remove the background-attachment:fixed; to show how it should look)

Comment: use a separate div and put the background image centered inside that and then fix position the div

Comment: @Pamblam That produces the same unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrBPob I achieved the look you needed with:

```
background-position: 50% 70%;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Tweak the percentages to suit you. The first value is horizontal (X) and the second value is vertical (Y).

Comment: Is this really the best way to do it? It doesn't even seem to be properly responsive. The vertical centering doesn't align right when emulating on smaller view-port devices.

Comment: It's kind of hard to do that with a fixed background. You should try media queries to solve that problem. I'll make another example.

Comment: It's ok. I can do the media queries to get it to work for the different view ports. It's just kind of strange(more annoying) that both lines of CSS don't work hand in hand. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting if you think it was helpful enough.